# Ember.js flashes list contents when adding models - how do I fix?

Tags: pagination, ember.js

I am using Ember.js to build an application that uses Server-Sent Events to add and update a controller that implements paging. The full implementation of the controller is listed below.

```
    App.endpointsDisponiblesClass = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    loading: true,
    completeList:[
         /*
         App.Endpoint.create({
             id: 1,
             id_manufacturer: 1,
             id_model: 1,
             mac_address: '00:11:22:33:44:55',
             last_known_ipv4:   '10.0.0.1',
             last_scanned:      '2012-12-31',
             last_configured:   null
         }),
         */
    ],
    content:    [],
    offset: null,
    limit:  10,
    displaySlice: function(offset) {
        if (offset >= this.completeList.length)
            offset = this.completeList.length - 1;
        if (offset < 0) offset = 0;
        offset = offset - (offset % this.get('limit'));
        if (this.get('offset') == null || offset != this.offset) {
            var slice = this.completeList.slice(offset, offset + this.get('limit'));
            this.set('offset', offset);
            this.set('content', slice);             
        }
    },
    displayStart: function() { this.displaySlice(0); },
    displayPrevious: function() { this.displaySlice(this.offset - this.limit); },
    displayNext: function() { this.displaySlice(this.offset + this.limit); },
    displayEnd: function() { this.displaySlice(this.completeList.length); },
    startPosition: function() {
        return this.get('offset') + 1;
    }.property('offset'),
    endPosition: function() {
        var pos = this.get('offset') + this.get('limit');
        if (pos > this.completeList.length)
            pos = this.completeList.length;
        return pos;
    }.property('offset', 'limit'),
    displayRefresh: function() {
        console.debug('displayRefresh');
        var offset = this.get('offset');
        this.set('offset', null);
        this.displaySlice(offset);
    }.observes('completeList.@each')
});
App.endpointsDisponibles = App.endpointsDisponiblesClass.create();
```

The completeList element contains the full list of elements I want to page through, with one of them listed as a comment. In my implementation, I perform the paging by assigning slices of the full list to the 'content' element of the ArrayController subclass. Additionally there are some helper methods that get invoked from various views that display buttons for Next, Back, and so on.

The template fragment that renders the model list looks like this:

```
{{#view tagName="tbody"}}
{{#each App.endpointsDisponibles}}
<tr class="neo-table-data-row">
    <td class="neo-table-data-row">{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="isSelected"}}</td>
    <td class="neo-table-data-row">{{mac_address}}</td>
    <td class="neo-table-data-row"><a target="_blank" {{bindAttr href="adminUrl"}}>{{last_known_ipv4}}</a></td>
    <td class="neo-table-data-row">{{name_manufacturer}}</td>
    <td class="neo-table-data-row">{{view Ember.Select
        contentBinding="modelSelect"
        optionValuePath="content.id_model"
        optionLabelPath="content.name_model"
        valueBinding="id_model"
        disabledBinding="App.endpointScanController.scanInProgress"}}</td>
</tr>
{{else}}
<tr class="neo-table-data-row">
    <td class="neo-table-data-row" colspan="7">No endpoints have been discovered or loaded.</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
{{/view}}
```

I prepare an EventSource with an onmessage handler that parses a JSON message from the server, and updates the completeList, by adding/updating/removing models as required on completeList. Since I observe completeList.@each with displayRefresh(), the page slice gets updated in case I view the last page and a model is added, or if one of the viewed models is removed. So far, it works perfectly.

The problem is that half of the time a message triggers an insert, the re-rendering of the template is awfully visible to the user. The template gets emptied, remains empty for about a fraction of a second, and is then refilled with the proper contents. The other half of the time, the template contents get smoothly updated without emptying and refilling, which is what I want. The SSE message stream is bursty - it is idle for a few seconds, then fires some 5 to 6 messages in less than a second, then the cycle repeats. The ugly rendering has been observed in both Firefox and Google Chrome.

In Firefox, I have installed Firebug, and I can invoke the controller methods from the console. When I do that, they behave exactly as in the SSE case. Sometimes the refresh is smooth, and sometimes the emptying and refilling of the template is visible.

What can I do to ensure that the template rendering is consistently smooth?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem - this question is the only result that came up in my google searches for "arraycontroller flash".

The problem comes about when I reset the model of an array controller:

```
      @set 'model', message
```

<strike>The interesting thing is that I've got an almost-identical application that I've built using knockout - and that has no flashing / refresh issues.</strike>

I stumbled across this post: [Mitigating a flickering UI when refreshing content in Ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883553/mitigating-a-flickering-ui-when-refreshing-content-in-ember) and ended up wrapping my update in an Ember.run function, which solved the flickering, but it still seems wrong to me.

```
      Ember.run =>
        @set 'model', message
```

[ deleted complete red herring ]

<strike>As of now it seems that the correct path is to wrap in Ember.run - ugly as all hell, but it does solve the immediate problem. My guess is that Ember isn't quite as optimized / fast as knockout is, or Ember has a bug with the queuing of the updates. Hopefully it will improve as time goes on.</strike>

EDIT 7/23/13 -

I realized after I wrote this that Ember is completely right, and I was completely wrong. (and the knockout thing is incidental)

As described here: http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/managing-asynchrony/ it seems that Ember uses events to bundle updates together - effectively wrapping an event handler in Ember.run

But in my case (and I think yours) we're calling an ajax method, which is asynchronous. The callback (or promise - same problem) happens after the Ember event has fired and returned. So Ember has no way of knowing that it needs to queue up the updates.

Still not sure that the "correct" solution is to wrap it in Ember.run - the docs (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html) seem to indicate that it's not right, but the docs also push towards Ember Data, which wouldn't have this problem.

Guess I need to read up on Ember's runloop some more.